# How to find out why svm considers a particular observation a support vector?

Tags: r, svm

Following an example in *An Introduction to Statistical Learning* (James et al. 2015) I trained a Support Vector Machine on some dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(40), ncol = 2)
y <- c(rep(-1, 10), rep(1, 10))
data <- data.frame(x = x, y = as.factor(y))
svmfit <- svm(y ~ ., data = data, kernel = "linear", cost = 10, scale = F)
plot(svmfit, data, xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3))
```

This gives:

[image]

In this plot, according to `?plot.svm` support vectors are identified by an 'x'. **My question is:** why is the yellow circled observation a support vector whilst other observations clearly closer to the decision boundary (e. g. the blue circled one) are not?